# HTML how to align the columns in on line?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an `HTML` page in which I am displaying some values.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Table Upper-->
<section class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Energy Charge</th>
        <th scope="col">E-Arrears</th>
        <th scope="col">I-Tax</th>
        <th scope="col">GST</th>
        <th scope="col">E-Tax</th>
        <th scope="col">F-Tax</th>
        <th scope="col">R.G.S.T</th>
        <th scope="col">Total Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">Amt W Due date</th>
        <th scope="col">Amt A Due date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>26,096</td>
        <td>3,433</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>5,020</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>34,549</td>
        <td>34,549</td>
        <td>34,845</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--End-->

  <!--Horizontal Table 2-->
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col ">C-Duty</th>
        <th scope="col ">Rd Maint</th>
        <th scope="col ">Mosque</th>
        <th scope="col ">Conserve</th>
        <th scope="col ">Sewerage</th>
        <th scope="col ">Misc</th>
        <th scope="col ">Sanitation</th>
        <th scope="col ">Tv fee</th>
        <th scope="col ">Rent</th>
        <th scope="col ">Rent Arrear</th>
        <th scope="col ">Amt W Due date</th>
        <th scope="col ">Amt A Due date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>350</td>
        <td>350</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>925</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>24,15</td>
        <td>24,15</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--end-->


  <!--Horizontal Table 3-->
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col ">F/MRC</th>
        <th scope="col ">F/MRC Arrears</th>
        <th scope="col ">Water Charges</th>
        <th scope="col ">Water Arrears</th>
        <th scope="col ">Total Amount</th>
        <th scope="col ">Amt W.Due Date</th>
        <th scope="col ">Amt A.Due Date</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1,060</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1,060</td>
        <td>1,060</td>
        <td>1,070</td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--end-->

  <!--Horizontal Table 4-->
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Grand Total</td>
        <td>38,024</td>
        <td>39,339</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

**Output**

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

I want to set the column size to the size of the first `Amt W Due date` and `Amt A Due date`. i.e. all the amounts with due and after due date till grand total values should be aligned in one column.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Note:** I have more than one sections and each section have tables inside it.

Comment: where is your css styles?

Comment: Automatic width and alignment of columns are a feature available _inside_ a table. You can not expect that to work across _multiple_ tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Using inline style: adding `style="width:10%"` to the columns

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Table Upper-->
<section class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Energy Charge</th>
        <th scope="col">E-Arrears</th>
        <th scope="col">I-Tax</th>
        <th scope="col">GST</th>
        <th scope="col">E-Tax</th>
        <th scope="col">F-Tax</th>
        <th scope="col">R.G.S.T</th>
        <th scope="col">Total Amount</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Amt W Due date</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Amt A Due date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>26,096</td>
        <td>3,433</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>5,020</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>34,549</td>
        <td>34,549</td>
        <td>34,845</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--End-->

  <!--Horizontal Table 2-->
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col ">C-Duty</th>
        <th scope="col ">Rd Maint</th>
        <th scope="col ">Mosque</th>
        <th scope="col ">Conserve</th>
        <th scope="col ">Sewerage</th>
        <th scope="col ">Misc</th>
        <th scope="col ">Sanitation</th>
        <th scope="col ">Tv fee</th>
        <th scope="col ">Rent</th>
        <th scope="col ">Rent Arrear</th>
        <th scope="col " style="width:10%">Amt W Due date</th>
        <th scope="col " style="width:10%">Amt A Due date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>350</td>
        <td>350</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>925</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>24,15</td>
        <td>24,15</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--end-->


  <!--Horizontal Table 3-->
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col ">F/MRC</th>
        <th scope="col ">F/MRC Arrears</th>
        <th scope="col ">Water Charges</th>
        <th scope="col ">Water Arrears</th>
        <th scope="col ">Total Amount</th>
        <th scope="col " style="width:10%">Amt W.Due Date</th>
        <th scope="col " style="width:10%">Amt A.Due Date</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1,060</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1,060</td>
        <td>1,060</td>
        <td>1,070</td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--end-->

  <!--Horizontal Table 4-->
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Grand Total</td>
        <td style="width:10%">38,024</td>
        <td style="width:10%">39,339</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

(if you open the result in full page you can see the correct allignment)

2. using external style: i.e. by adding a class to the two columns, then setting the style in the CSS file

```css
.eqAllign {
    width:10%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Table Upper-->
<section class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Energy Charge</th>
        <th scope="col">E-Arrears</th>
        <th scope="col">I-Tax</th>
        <th scope="col">GST</th>
        <th scope="col">E-Tax</th>
        <th scope="col">F-Tax</th>
        <th scope="col">R.G.S.T</th>
        <th scope="col">Total Amount</th>
        <th scope="col" class="eqAllign">Amt W Due date</th>
        <th scope="col" class="eqAllign">Amt A Due date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>26,096</td>
        <td>3,433</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>5,020</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>34,549</td>
        <td>34,549</td>
        <td>34,845</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--End-->

  <!--Horizontal Table 2-->
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col ">C-Duty</th>
        <th scope="col ">Rd Maint</th>
        <th scope="col ">Mosque</th>
        <th scope="col ">Conserve</th>
        <th scope="col ">Sewerage</th>
        <th scope="col ">Misc</th>
        <th scope="col ">Sanitation</th>
        <th scope="col ">Tv fee</th>
        <th scope="col ">Rent</th>
        <th scope="col ">Rent Arrear</th>
        <th scope="col " class="eqAllign">Amt W Due date</th>
        <th scope="col " class="eqAllign">Amt A Due date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>350</td>
        <td>350</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>925</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>24,15</td>
        <td>24,15</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--end-->


  <!--Horizontal Table 3-->
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col ">F/MRC</th>
        <th scope="col ">F/MRC Arrears</th>
        <th scope="col ">Water Charges</th>
        <th scope="col ">Water Arrears</th>
        <th scope="col ">Total Amount</th>
        <th scope="col " class="eqAllign">Amt W.Due Date</th>
        <th scope="col " class="eqAllign">Amt A.Due Date</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1,060</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1,060</td>
        <td>1,060</td>
        <td>1,070</td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--end-->

  <!--Horizontal Table 4-->
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Grand Total</td>
        <td class="eqAllign">38,024</td>
        <td class="eqAllign">39,339</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```